# Charset is set incorrectly to us-ascii instead of utf-8 when sending email from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, httprequest, http, email-studio, character-encoding

We have an issue where an email sent from a journey is rendered with '????????' instead of Hebrew letters. We examine the mime code header (within the .eml file) and found this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

This can explain why the Hebrew letters rendered as '????????'. Then we copied the email in email studio and send it again. This time the Hebrew characters rendered well and the mime code header looks like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"    
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

**The question is what determines the encoding Marketing Cloud set to the message? In this case both messages are identical and MC sends them with different encoding each time.**

Thanks a lot,
Barak

Comment: Can you confirm the email in which you had `charset="us-ascii"` was built using the templates available on platform? or was built with HTML email by placing full HTML code developed by your Internal teams?

Comment: Hi @VishalKumarCV thanks for your comment. The email was developed using full HTML code (not template-based). Both of the email (which are identical) were developed using custom html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the 'email overview' section that shows when you first click an email, you will notice in the left side, a small section titled 'Language'. This shows the currently set charset.

[image]

If you need to change this, then go to the edit button in the top right and choose 'Edit Properties'.  Here you can change the 'Target Language' which is to the right of the 'Location' field and right below the 'Sharing' section.

[image]

There is no need to recreate anything, this change will adjust the charset accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington! This is exactly what I was searching for.